# Java extends vs object reference?

Tags: java, android, class, extend

I'm working on a android app, and I have a user class that has properties about the user. I also have a class that has views (i.e. TextViews) that shows the appropriate property on the screen, these are for GUI purposes. This GUI class needs the properties of the user class so I can access those too. So I am left with a decision to make that I am not sure. I want to pick the one that's better in programming practices. I don't want to merge all the properties including the GUI together in one class.

The way I see it is, I could either have the GUI class extend the user class or have the GUI class have a private global variable which holds the user object.

Does anyone know which is better and why?

Comment: If you have this choice, and you don't have a good reason to use `extends`, don't use `extends`. The other way is much less likely to cause headaches later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) is better. It makes no sense for a GUI class to *extend* a 'user' class -- the two don't possess any sort of ["is-a"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) relationship. It *does* make sense, however, for the GUI class to maintain a user object to work with.

In other words, it doesn't make sense to say a GUI object *is a* user object, but it does make sense to say a GUI object *contains* user a user object.

Lastly, you generally want to keep your front-end and back-end as separate and modular as possible. Having your GUI class extend your user class undermines this principle.

Comment: In my case, the gui class is not going to contain a list of people, its more like, for every user object, there is also a GUI object. In that sense I could combine the properties of both classes, but I don't want to, because some other classes might just need the user object without the GUI properties...

Comment: @omega Right, so in that case you shouldn't combine them by inheritance. You can still use encapsulation with the GUI class.

Comment: Which class goes on the outside then?

Comment: @omega From what you describe, the GUI class should certainly go on the outside. The user objects shouldn't know anything about the GUI, but the GUI needs to maintain a user object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any of your choices as a good programming practice according to `MVC architecture` (which is what Android uses).

Neither having the GUI class(part of UI layer) extend the `User class`(part of Model layer) or having in the GUI class a reference to a `User` is a good idea(IMHO). The interaction between the Model and the UI should be delegated to your `Controller`(the `Activity`)

As a side note, there are other languages like `Objective-C` were you could use a `Category`. With categories you could decorate your UI classes for doing this kind of things, without violating the architecture.